# How to calculate when a specific semigroup is closed under conjugation by this group.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, semigroups

Let $\mathcal{T}_n$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices such that $X\in \mathcal{T}_n$ can be written as:
  $$X = \bigl( \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \overline{0} \\
T & \underline{0}  
\end{array} \bigr)
$$
Such that $\overline{0}$ and $\underline{0}$ are the $n-1$ dimensional row vector and column vector of zeros respectively and $T$ is a binary $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ lower triangular matrix with exactly one "1" in each row.

Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ be the set of matrices
$$Y = \bigl( \begin{array}{cc}
 1 &  \overline{0} \\
\underline{0} & P   
\end{array} \bigr)
$$
Such that $P$ is an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ permutation matrix.  We define an indicator function for every $X \in \mathcal{T}_n$ and $Y \in \mathcal{P}_n$ as follows:
$$ I(X,Y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $YXY^{-1} \in \mathcal{T}_n$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Question: Calculate $Z(n) = \sum_{X \in \mathcal{T}_n} \sum_{Y \in \mathcal{P}_n}  I(X,Y)$.

The first thing that I noticed is that $\mathcal{T}_n$ does not form a group (it's not closed under taking inverses) but it does form a semigroup  and I hoped to find a slick proof using this fact. I have also attempted to find an appropriate recursion/ induction argument to solve this problem but so far I have failed on both counts.

Comment: In the original matrix $X$, you presumably want either the $T$ in the lower right corner or the $1$ in the upper right corner.